# Python collection for create if missing, update if existing

Tags: python, data-structures

The programming pattern I want to implement is: create an object, if it is missing from the collection
add it to the collection, else update the equivalent object in the collection.

```
class PersonStats(object):
    def __init__(self, i):
        super(PersonStats, self).__init__()
        self.id = i
        self.stats = 0

    def update_stats(self):
        self.stats += 1

    def __key(self):
        return self.id

    def __eq__(self, y):
        return self.__key() == y.__key()

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.__key())


s = set_like_collection()

special_person = PersonStats(22222)

r = s.find(special_person)
if r is not None:
    r.update_stats()
else:
    s.add(r)
```

I was surprised to learn that Python's set does not have a find function. (One needs to iterate the set to find the object she desire)
I know I can use defaultdict but I hate to break the encapsulation of PersonStats, That is, in the above example, use the person's id out
side of the class PersonStats.

So my question is do you know of a data structure in Python that would let me have an unordered_set and let me find in it in constant time?
Also would like to know if I am thinking of it all wrong.
Also if you know why Python's set does not have find function.

Comment: To find if an object is in a set you use `in`, for example `a in my_set`.

Comment: `find` has only sense when it returns a position in the object. Since `set` is unordered, `in` is enough to tell you if the object is in the set or not.

Comment: And `in` is constant time.

Comment: Don't store mutable objects in a set.  That way lies madness.  A set is meant to contain immutable objects only, which is why it doesn't have `find()`:  The only relevant information is whether an object is in the set or not, and retrieving it isn't useful in any way.  Use a dictrionary mapping the keys to objects instead.  You don't have to use a `defaultdict`.  A plain dictionary will do just fine.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre A `find()` method does not necessarily have to return an index.  It could also return the found object itself, which is what the OP seems to have been hoping for.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, I see what you mean. That is a limiting decision of python's part. I can take care of myself and make sure that the key is not mutated and only other parts of my class are.

Comment: I can't really see a disadvantage of using a dictionary here, so I don't see this as limiting.  If you give your class a `key` property you are not really breaking encapsulation.  Your code will become simpler as well.  You won't need to define `__eq__` and `__hash__`, and your definition of `__eq__` was confusing anyway, since two `PersonStats` instances with completely different content would compare equal if only their key matches.

Comment: Thank you @SvenMarnach, That is a really good point. The surprising behavior in compare is really unclean and must be removed from the class. I am convinced now that defaultdict is way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use an ordered set:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordered-set

The `.index(...)` function delivers the 'position' in the set.
You might want to catch exceptions, though.